# Way to replace field in views to image by hook instead of using template

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, hook, drupal-themes

Is there a way to replace the value in view of a field to image?

i.e: value = 101, so display `<img src=/myfiles/101.gif>` in hook / theme_() function instead of using a .tpl file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) you can simply change the settings of the field in a similar fashion to:
[image: Rewrite the output of a field]

Comment: wow dude thanks for the investment of time to do this screen shot +1!